# JavaScript JSON object not parsing

Tags: javascript, ajax

Here's my JS code from a success section of an AJAX call:

```
success: function(msg){
    var data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(msg));
    $("#searchResults").html(data + " Value for 'a': " + data.color + "\nValue for 'b': " + data.message);
}
```

Here's what's printed on the page:

```
{"color":"Yellow","message":"Pending"} Value for 'a': undefined Value for 'b': undefined
```

Why are they undefined?

Comment: Remove the JSON.stringify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data` in the `console.log` seems to be a string still, like @Musa said, you need to remove the `JSON.stringify`

Answer (score 0):

If your ajax response is JSON you should explicitly state so in the request so that it will be parsed automatically for you by jQuery.ajax . `dataType: 'json'`

```
$.ajax({
...
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data){
        $("#searchResults").html(" Value for 'a': " + data.color + "\nValue for 'b': " + data.message);
    }
...
```